# Linq Query Return List of Records instead of displaying single record

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I trying to developing banking system . I trying to join three tables records into single table . but the problem is when i compile it i got following errors.

> Error CS1929  'IOrderedQueryable<>' does not contain
>   a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload
>   'ParallelEnumerable.Concat<>(ParallelQuery<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<>

Here is my Linq Query .

```
  public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
            {

                var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
                using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
                {

        var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new
                {
                    w.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                    w.Date
                }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new
                {
                    d.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                    d.Date
                })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
             .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
             {
                 //You should perform same anonymous type which you want to concat
                 Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
                 Deposit = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance,
                 Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                e.Account_Fees
             }));


                    var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                    return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string
                }
            }
        }
```

This is DBContext class.

```
  public partial class HalifaxDatabaseEntities : DbContext
        {
            public HalifaxDatabaseEntities()
                : base("name=HalifaxDatabaseEntities")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public virtual DbSet<Web_User_login> Web_User_login { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<USER> USERS { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<tblUser> tblUsers { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Holder_Details> Current_Account_Holder_Details { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Details> Current_Account_Details { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Deposit> Current_Account_Deposit { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Withdraw> Current_Account_Withdraw { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the Model Class ..
[image]
Here is the Database record [image]

Here is the Result i Expect when i clicked the account number its should display the specific record [image]

Comment: Seems like you are not using the parameter to your linq which is `string Account_Number`

Comment: if you got that error from above supposed to be you don't have this output from below.

Comment: .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
                {
                    e.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance=(decimal?)e.Account_Balance

                }));

Comment: what will happen if you don't add that line? is the data completed or not?

Comment: its returning list of record but i want to display the record when i enter account number input filed then click the submit button

Comment: are you even checking for the account number in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only Concat locally. Try adding a .ToList() before each Concat so it materialize the records locally before concatenating.

Note: your Where clause is only applying to Current_Account_Deposit. Withdraw and Details will return all records.

Try to generate 3 basic context queries. One for each table and finish each one with ToList(). Later concatenate all 3 lists into one list using Concat.

This will make you understand the concept and you can move forward from here.

```
var q1 = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new
    {
        w.Account_Number,
        Deposit = (decimal?)null,
        Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
        w.Date
    }).ToList();

    var q2 = context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new
    {
        d.Account_Number,
        Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
        Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
        d.Date
    }).OrderBy(r => r.Date).ToList();

    var q3 = context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
         {
             //You should perform same anonymous type which you want to concat
             Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
             Deposit = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance,
             Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
             e.Account_Fees
         }).ToList();

    var inOut = q1.Concat(q2).Concat(q3).ToList();
```

You may need to add the same Where clause to q2 and Q3. I wasn't sure if you wanted that.

Comment: You can only concat lists of the same format. q1 and q2 return lists of objects that have a different format then q3. q3 as field Account_Fees instead of Date. Just make them all equal.

Comment: Technically those are not list of `record`s but a list of anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that you have already the list of records.

It should look like.

```
var getList = inOut.Where(x=>x.Account_Number == 
Account_Number).FirstOrDefault();
```

if your `inOut` is a true result of a list.

Comment: well this is the answer but my point is why to perform other concats unneccesarily when we can put the where clause just in the beginning

Comment: This is three tables record and joining into single record and display it into angular js application

Answer (score 0):

I have added where clause before select `.Where(x=> x.Account_Number == accountNumber)`

Change this :

```
 var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Select(w => new
            {
                w.Account_Number,
                Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                w.Date
            }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new
            {
                d.Account_Number,
                Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                d.Date
            })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
            .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
            {
                e.Account_Number,
                Account_Balance=(decimal?)e.Account_Balance
            }));
```

To :

```
 var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x=> x.Account_Number == accountNumber ).Select(w => new
            {
                w.Account_Number,
                Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                w.Date
            }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new
            {
                d.Account_Number,
                Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                d.Date
            })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
            .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
            {
                e.Account_Number,
                Account_Balance=(decimal?)e.Account_Balance
            }));
```

As You need to get the specific `accountnumber` details before performing concat

Comment: Is it woking now as expected?

Comment: also try moving `Current_Account_Details` before deposit and withdrawl

Comment: Error CS1929 'IOrderedQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Concat<>(ParallelQuery<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<>

Comment: 1) You need to place `.Where(x=> x.Account_Number == accountNumber )` also in query with `Current_Account_Withdraw`; 2) You try to perform `UNION ALL` operation on 3 subqueries there 2 of them have same number and type of columns, but 3rd subquery has another number and type of columns; 3) `OrderBy` must be after 3rd `Concat`. I think your error about this.

Comment: UPD. `.Where(x=> x.Account_Number == accountNumber )` also need for 3rd subquery with `Current_Account_Details`

Comment: @Mohammad, to place answer we all need some details of what do you want to receive. Using `Concat` (which translated to sql `UNION ALL`) doesn't match with your screenshot. On screenshot you have view with columns from all of 3 tables, it is not a `UNION ALL`. It is `SELECT <table1.columns>, <table2.columns>, <table3.columns>`.  In LINQ it is `SelectMany` with filter to show records only for one `account_number`

Comment: @Mohammad, there is 3(!!!) records with `account_number == 15` on your screenshot. But you want just 1. And as I understood, if you want just 1 row , and im my understanding it is **total** row, then you must calculate the summ of deposit and witdraw amounts apart. But what to do with dates? You also want dates and the dates of each operation may be different. On the one hand you want filter by account_number, but on the other hand you wand single row. What data to accumulate in this line, that's the question?! In any case, this problem **can not be solved by using Concat**.

Comment: @HemidAbbasov  I trying to join three tables records into single table and display this single record in web page  . but the problem is when i compile it i got following errors. When I enter account number and click the submit button then I want to display that account number record . That all nothing else